# Autorefesh of outputted result from connected sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have a question regarding the connected sheet function in google sheets. I have several connected sheets with custom queries. There are all connected to the same parameters in sheet, so that they should update if the values in A1 and A2 of my sheet are updated. However, right now I am manually updating all of the output results from my connected sheets by pressing the update button at the bottom left on each of them.
I want the query itself to only run when the values in A1 and A2 are updated, so they will not be set to have regular automatic updates.

Is there any way, using google app script or such, to get the output of the connected sheets to update every time the value is changed in A1 and A2, without setting the queries themselves to regular automatic updates?

Comment: just making sure I'm on the right page, the output you get on A1 and A2, is it coming from the results of other formulas or is it a value you entered manually?